# MapManager - Mapserver

Tags: mapserver, p-mapper, map-manager

I'm using MapManager to create the file .map but I can't understand how mapserver opens this file, I try to see the folder of pmapper where there is the demo file. I put the my .map file there and then, I changed the path of mapserver but it is not the right way.

Comment: thank you, I tried to use the link but I don't find the page

Comment: the link to the demo page is: http://localhost/pmapper/map_default.phtml but it's quit different from yours. thanks

Comment: I tried to modify your link in these way:                     http://localhost/pmapper//executable?map=path/to/prova.map&other=requestsparams&



http://localhost/pmapper/executable?map=C:\ms4w\apps\mapserv-demo/to/prova.map&other=requestsparams&                                                                                                      the file name is "prova.map" I put it in the same folder where I found the demo file .map

Comment: thanks as soon as I try

Comment: I wrote:
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\ms4w\apps\mapserv-demo/to/prova.map&

I get:
msLoadMap(): Unable to access file. (C:\ms4w\apps\mapserv-demo/to/prova.map) 


I wrote:
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?C:\ms4w\apps\mapserv-demo/to/prova.map&

I get:
msCGILoadMap(): Web application error. CGI variable "map" is not set.

Comment: the path to the .map file is: C:\ms4w\apps\pmapper\pmapper_demodata\prova.map

Comment: mapserv(): Web application error. Traditional BROWSE mode requires a TEMPLATE in the WEB section, but none was provided.

Comment: That's working then.  That is the URL to which a client appends appropriate request parameters.  So for example if you've allowed  a WMS, the following request would give an XML response.  `http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\ms4w\apps\pmapper\pmapper_demodata\prova.map&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&`

Comment: Sembra che il file XML specificato non abbia un foglio di stile associato. L’albero del documento è visualizzato di seguito.
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">
<ServiceException>
msWMSGetCapabilities(): WMS server error. WMS request not enabled. Check wms/ows_enable_request settings.
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>

Comment: if i don't need a wms ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

MapServer can find/access the map file (or files) though a number of mechanisms, such as the global configuration file for version 8, and/or in a web server configuration file, and/or you can call it as part of the request like (using your configuration example):

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\ms4w\apps\pmapper\pmapper_demodata\prova.map&
```

This is the  URL to which a client appends appropriate request parameters. So *for example* **if** you've allowed a WMS, the following request would give an XML response.

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\ms4w\apps\pmapper\pmapper_demodata\prova.map&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&
```